# How to get AD user details (azure-mobile-apps-node)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I successfully logged in with AD authentication and redirect to my API page (API page is given below)

I tried "req.azureMobile.user" and "req.user" but both are not returning user details.

I am trying this in desktop browsers

```
var azureStorage = require('azure-storage');
var azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');

var api = {
    get: function (req, res, next) {
        res.status(200).send(req.azureMobile.user);
        // alternative code i tried
        // res.status(200).send(req.user);
    }
};
module.exports = api;
```

Comment: Which user details do you mean?  The ones in /.auth/me or the ones inside the token?  Does req.azureMobile.user produce any information?

Comment: inside the token. no req.azureMobile.user giving me "undefind"

Comment: What does your request to the backend look like?  What headers are you including?